# Difference between java.util.Scanner and java.util.Scanner.*

Tags: java

```
// imports all classes of util package    
import java.util.*;

// imports Scanner class of util package
import java.util.Scanner;

// what does this do?
import java.util.Scanner.*;
```

Is `Scanner` a package here?

**Edit:** Ok so import `java.util.Scanner.*` imports the public nested classes. But what if there was also a package called `Scanner`? What would the statement `import java.util.Scanner.*` do then?

Comment: That last line doesn't compile, does it?

Comment: [Read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sure it does

Comment: @arshajii: With `Scanner` not being a package name? Interesting.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, That `java.util.Scanner` happens to be the name of a class does not make it an invalid package name -- they are two separate namespaces so there's no conflict, and the lower-case convention for package names is not compiler-enforced.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Yes, but my point is, there is no `java.util.Scanner` package. :-) So that line won't compile.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just wrote a small test program with that line; it definitely *does* compile.

Comment: Yeah even I was surprised.
Seems that the statement does not check the presence of public nested classes. I just imports them(if any).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, My understanding is that it is possible to specify a sourcepath/classpath to javac that makes it impossible to distinguish between non-existent packages and packages with zero public non-annotation-classes.

Comment: @abhinavpandey And that makes perfect sense. When you have `import x.*` where `x` is a normal package (e.g. `java.util`), `x` is not checked for being non-empty.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

This imports `Scanner` (as you already know).

```
import java.util.Scanner.*;
```

*This* imports any public [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) defined within `Scanner`.

This particular import statement is useless, as `Scanner` does not define any nested classes (and the import does not import `Scanner` itself). However, this can be used with something like `import java.util.Map.*`, in which case [`Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) (an interface nested in `Map` that is commonly used when dealing with maps) will be imported. I'm sure there are better examples, this is just the one that came to mind.

All of this is specified in [JLS §7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5) (specifically, see [§7.5.1: Single-Type-Import Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1)).

---

In response to the OP's edit:

> Ok so import `java.util.Scanner.*` imports the public nested classes. But what if there was also a package called `Scanner`? What would the statement `import java.util.Scanner.*` do then?

In this case there would be a compilation error, since the package `java.util.Scanner` would collide with the type `java.util.Scanner`.

Answer (score 16):

The asterisk after the classname imports public nested classes.

From the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html):

> Note: Another, less common form of import allows you to import the
>   public nested classes of an enclosing class. For example, if the
>   graphics.Rectangle class contained useful nested classes, such as
>   Rectangle.DoubleWide and Rectangle.Square, you could import Rectangle
>   and its nested classes by using the following two statements.

```
import graphics.Rectangle; 
import graphics.Rectangle.*;
```

> Be aware that the second import statement will not import Rectangle.